# registerApexTestWireAdapter is deprecated when working through trailhead Lightning Web Components Tests

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have been working through trailhead from link below
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components

and noticed I got a console.warn error

console.warn
registerApexTestWireAdapter is deprecated. More details: https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-version-2.x-to-3.x.md

I looked over the documentation was a little unsure of how to proceeded with it. If registerApexTestWireAdapter is deprecated would I be safe to assume that it should not be used in a project? Also if I wanted to do a jest test for a LWC component that was say as simple as the code shown below. What would be the desired alternative to not receive an console.warn message?

```
@wire(Contacts)contacts;
```

what would be the desired alternative to

```
import { registerApexTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/practiceLWCController.getContacts';

// ...test below here

it('displays contacts', () => {
        const element = createElement('practice-lwc', {
            is: PracticeLWC
        });

        document.body.appendChild(element);
        getContactsAdapter.emit(mockContacts);

        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            const contacts = Array.from(element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.contact'));
            expect(contacts.length).toBe(3);
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[createApexTestWireAdapter](https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util/pull/36) was added to replace `registerApexTestWireAdapter`. From the documentation you linked

> Notice that when testing an apex method used with @wire, you should
> change your apex method mock to use createApexTestWireAdapter

You can remove your references to `registerApextestWireAdapter` and do the following to mock a wired custom apex call

```javascript
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/practiceLWCController.getContacts';


jest.mock(
    "@salesforce/apex/practiceLWCController.getContacts",
    () => {
        const { createApexTestWireAdapter } = require("@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest");
        return {
            default: createApexTestWireAdapter(jest.fn()),
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);

//later in your tests

getContacts.emit(mockContacts);
```

Another good reference would be the lwc-recipes which demonstrates this as well for your specific scenario - [apexWireMethodToProperty.test.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexWireMethodToProperty/__tests__/apexWireMethodToProperty.test.js)